# jquery - using stoppropagation for multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using stopPropegation to aid me in the way my dropdowns work.

I am using it for multiple dropdowns to help me keep the dropdown open but if the user clicks anywhere else on the page then it will slide up the menu.

HTML

```
<nav id="moo">
<ul>
<li>Item 1 <i>o</i>
<div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>Item 1 <i>o</i>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="login-top">Login</div>


<div id="user">roooar</div>
```

CSS

```
ul { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
li { display: inline; }
nav li { position: relative; }
nav i { cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; background-color: red;padding: 5px; }
.dropdown { display: none; position: absolute; border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; }  
.dropdown li {
display: block;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

#login-top {
background:blue;
padding:10px;
color:white;
margin-top:30px
}

#user {
background:pink;
margin-top:10px;
padding:50px;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
    $('#login-top').click(function () {

    var $user = $('#user');

    if ($('#user').is(':visible')) {
        $user.slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $user.slideUp(300);
        $user.slideDown(300);
    }
});

$('nav > ul > li').click(function (e) {
var $childDropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown');

if ($childDropdown.is(':visible')) {

    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!$(target).parents(".dropdown").length) {
        $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
    }    
} else {
    $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
    $childDropdown.slideDown(300);
}
});

/* Anything that gets to the document
will hide the dropdown */
$(document).click(function () {
$(".dropdown").hide();
$("#user").slideUp();
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
it past the dropdown itself */
$("nav, #login-top, #user").click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I have 2 questions really about this.

1. Say if I click open the dropdown menu because I have included certain elements to be exempt from clicking elsewhere on the page - If I click anywhere else it will slide back up exactly how I want.

However, if I happen to click on the #login-top this will not make it slide up as I have added it to the code for the stopPropagation

Is there a may of making it work so that when `".dropdown"` is active then you can click absolutely everywhere (including on the `<div id='login'>` And then when `"#login"` and `"#user"` is active you can click anywhere on `"nav"` and it will still slide up the `div`?

1. Is it the right thing to be doing by grouping all the classes and id's into the code:

   $("nav, #login-top, #user").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    });

(I am struggling to explain this but hopefully you can see what I mean if you look at the fiddle version)

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/Nt2ZM/1/